# Replacing delegate methods that return values

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

Using ReactiveCocoa is a cleaner and centralized way to handle events than delegate methods, however I was wondering if it is possible to replace even the methods that return values without losing its value.

In the example below, the method `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` from `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` is called, but the method signature expects a BOOL return value to be effective. This way, the gesture recognizer just don't work, as if the method returned `NO`

Is it possible to use RAC to replace this kind of method?

```
[[self rac_signalForSelector:@selector(gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:)
                         fromProtocol:@protocol(UIGestureRecognizerDelegate)]
 subscribeNext:^(id x){
    NSLog(@"Was called, but how do I return the actual permission value?");
}];

self.backgroundTapGesture.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to use RAC to replace this kind of method?

Nope. `-rac_signalForSelector:` cannot be used on selectors of non-existent methods, of non-void return types. In these cases, implement the method to return a desired value. This makes it an existent method, which `-rac_signalForSelector:` can be applied to.